# Reorient dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to get the quantity of `electores` and `votes` in a single row.

I have this data set:

```py
electores = pd.DataFrame([['fdt','concejal','Escuela 1','X1001','350','positivo','4'],
                            ['jxc','concejal','Escuela 1','X1001','350','positivo','5'],
                            ['fdt','diputado','Escuela 1','X1001','350','positivo','4'],
                            ['jxc','diputado','Escuela 1','X1001','350','positivo','2'],
                            ['fdt','concejal','Escuela 1','X1002','350','positivo','4'],
                            ['jxc','concejal','Escuela 1','X1002','350','positivo','5'],
                            ['fdt','diputado','Escuela 1','X1002','350','positivo','3'],
                            ['jxc','diputado','Escuela 1','X1002','350','positivo','2'],
                            ['','concejal','Escuela 1','X1001','350','negativo','2'],
                            ['','concejal','Escuela 1','X1002','350','negarivo','2'],
                            ['','diputado','Escuela 1','X1001','350','negativo','4'],
                            ['','diputado','Escuela 1','X1002','350','negartivo','0']],
columns = ['agrup','cargo','estable','mesa','electores','tipo_de_voto','cantidad'])
```

| agrup | cargo | estable | mesa | electores | tipo_de_voto | cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fdt | concejal | Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | positivo | 4 |
| jxc | concejal | Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | positivo | 5 |
| fdt | diputado | Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | positivo | 4 |
| jxc | diputado | Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | positivo | 2 |
| fdt | concejal | Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | positivo | 4 |
| jxc | concejal | Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | positivo | 5 |
| fdt | diputado | Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | positivo | 3 |
| jxc | diputado | Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | positivo | 2 |
|  | concejal | Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | negativo | 2 |
|  | concejal | Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | negativo | 2 |
|  | diputado | Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | negativo | 4 |
|  | diputado | Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | negativo | 0 |

The expect result would be

| estable | mesa | electores | concejales_positivo_fdt | diputados_positivo_fdt | concejales_positivo_jxc | diputados_positivo_jxc | concejal_negativo | diputado_negarivo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Escuela 1 | X1001 | 35 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Escuela 1 | X1002 | 35 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pivot` then convert your multiindex to single index:

```
out = electores.pivot(index=['estable', 'mesa', 'electores'],
                      columns=['cargo', 'tipo_de_voto', 'agrup'],
                      values=['cantidad']).fillna(0)

out.columns = out.columns.droplevel(0).to_flat_index().str.join('_')
out = out.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     estable   mesa electores positivo_fdt positivo_jxc positivo_fdt positivo_jxc negativo_ negarivo_ negativo_ negartivo_
0  Escuela 1  X1001       350            4            5            4            2         2         0         4          0
1  Escuela 1  X1002       350            4            5            3            2         0         2         0          0
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I actually did not know about the `to_flat_index` method.

Comment: [`MultiIndex.to_flat_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_flat_index.html) converts to an index of tuples. After that you can use `str` accessor to join your tuples to a string.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is called pivoting.

```py
>>> electores
   agrup     cargo    estable   mesa electores tipo_de_voto cantidad
0    fdt  concejal  Escuela 1  X1001       350     positivo        4
1    jxc  concejal  Escuela 1  X1001       350     positivo        5
2    fdt  diputado  Escuela 1  X1001       350     positivo        4
3    jxc  diputado  Escuela 1  X1001       350     positivo        2
4    fdt  concejal  Escuela 1  X1002       350     positivo        4
5    jxc  concejal  Escuela 1  X1002       350     positivo        5
6    fdt  diputado  Escuela 1  X1002       350     positivo        3
7    jxc  diputado  Escuela 1  X1002       350     positivo        2
8         concejal  Escuela 1  X1001       350     negativo        2
9         concejal  Escuela 1  X1002       350     negarivo        2
10        diputado  Escuela 1  X1001       350     negativo        4
11        diputado  Escuela 1  X1002       350    negartivo        0

>>> electores.pivot(values='cantidad', columns=['agrup', 'tipo_de_voto', 'cargo'], index=['estable', 'mesa', 'electores'])

agrup                          fdt      jxc      fdt      jxc
tipo_de_voto              positivo positivo positivo positivo negativo negarivo negativo negartivo
cargo                     concejal concejal diputado diputado concejal concejal diputado  diputado
estable   mesa  electores
Escuela 1 X1001 350              4        5        4        2        2      NaN        4       NaN
          X1002 350              4        5        3        2      NaN        2      NaN         0
```

Note that in this solution, there are three levels of indexing for the columns. This will make it easier to get certain slices out of the table, though it can be flattened if you're sure that you want that.